# Android Studio 1.3 Gradle with 2 errors 1) The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound... 2) Cannot read packageName

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle with 2 errors:

1) The prefix "xmlns" cannot be bound to any namespace explicitly; neither can the namespace for "xmlns" be bound to any prefix explicitly.

2) Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\Map\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Trying to build a Maps Activity App and I get those 2 errors aforementioned in title with Android Studio 1.3.

Tried options 'Rebuild Project' and 'Clean Project' to no avail.
Read about a similar number 1 error issues. Still stuck.

Comment: check your manifest file it must have error in one of the tags or if you are using android studio then can you can directly go that file by selecting first error in console

Comment: I checked the Manifest file and the errors propagate from MapsActivity.java.

Comment: I checked the Manifest file and the errors propagate from MapsActivity.java. Looks like I may have to add some commands in the xmls file. Also, symbol 'R' cannot be resolved in  setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

Comment: check the xmls used in the MapsActivity some unwanted character might have added to one of the xml file

Comment: We cannot help you much without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case, that would include the code that is giving you these errors.

Comment: This is a portion of the code.  'R' is red: public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;
    private float last_x,last_y,last_z;
    long lastUpdate = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);//Cannot resolve 'R'
        setUpMapIfNeeded();